# What does the port of Selenium mean?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, port

[image]

This is the current iptables state.
The selenium chromeDriver web collector will not run in this state.

but

[image]

When all ports are open.

The selenium chromeDriver program works normally.

Drivers and programs run locally, not remotely.

Can you help me what the problem is?

Comment: Where do you see the problem? Where are you seeing _port of Selenium_?

Comment: Thanks but I solved it.
This was fixed by adding local interface related options in iptables configuration.

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT